# .desktop error “There was an error launching the application”

Tags: command-line

I'm in need of help.
trying to create a .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Doom 64
Exec=cd "/home/twitch/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Doom64" && wine DOOM64.EXE
Icon=/home/twitch/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Doom64/doom64.ico
Type=Application
Categories=Wine
```

but running into a error( “There was an error launching the application”)

Just run the command:

```
desktop-file-validate Doom64.desktop
```

and returned with:

```
Doom64.desktop: error: value "cd "/home/twitch/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Doom64" && wine DOOM64.EXE" for key "Exec" in group "Desktop Entry" contains a reserved character '&' outside of a quote
Doom64.desktop: error: value "cd "/home/twitch/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Doom64" && wine DOOM64.EXE" for key "Exec" in group "Desktop Entry" contains a reserved character '&' outside of a quote
Doom64.desktop: error: value "Wine;" for key "Categories" in group "Desktop Entry" contains an unregistered value "Wine"; values extending the format should start with "X-"
Doom64.desktop: hint: value "Wine;" for key "Categories" in group "Desktop Entry" does not contain a registered main category; application might only show up in a "catch-all" section of the application menu
```

What is the correct way to exec?

Comment: Exec Key isn't really a shell and don't know Boolean operators. Replace Exec key with `sh -c "cd /home/twitch/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Doom64 && wine DOOM64.EXE"` or `wine /home/twitch/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ (x86)/Doom64/DOOM64.EXE"`

Answer (score 0):

Make it like:

```
Exec=sh -c 'cd "/home/twitch/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Doom64" && wine DOOM64.EXE'
```

Alternatively, you can make a script and call the script from the `Exec=` line. The command line parser for `.desktop` files is much more primitive than your bash terminal prompt, and only supports parsing a single command and its arguments.

Comment: @steeldriver Indeed I messed up badly ;) Thank you for pointing out. I corrected this. Outer quotes can be single ' so escaping is not needed, although indeed double quotes with escaping would work, as would, in this case, double quotes outside and single quotes inside.